# Why was the question about seeing Jesus and his being God rejected?

Tags: discussion, support

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53565) was closed as asking for an opinion, and yet there is Scriptural reasoning as to how that phenomenon came about.

To me this is a cogent question about Christianity since it deals with something basic to the Belief in Christ as our Savior

My question is not meant to be adversarial only asking for help in understanding the rules covering the site.

Please help me to understand as often questions are closed and I cannot determine the reasoning behind their closure.

I have gone over the rules several times, and yet I seem to often offer answers to questions which quickly are closed.

I do not desire that the question be reopened only help so as not to be wasting a lot of time researching and answering a question which is soon after closed.

Thank you for your help and hopefully I can learn to be a better participant on the site.